# Read a word document (Docx) and modify it in Salesforce

Tags: apex, lightning, appexchange, xml, mail-merge

How can we open/read a word document (docx) and modify it from Salesforce (apex, aura, lwc or Appexchange)? The document is a mail merge template.  I need to do this, because mail merge is not supported in lightning and I need to develop it in lightning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that this is not practical to do in Salesforce.

It's technically possible, but there really aren't any tools to achieve this on-platform.

- It's possible to zip and unzip things in Apex ([Zippex](https://github.com/pdalcol/Zippex)), but the CPU and heap governor limits mean that only small files can be worked on
- Docx is a complex format (xml-based, uses the "open document format", it's a zip archive of many supporting files)

Answer (score 2):

Edit:

With the new ability to [compress and extract ZIP files in Apex](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_apex_compression.htm&release=248&type=5), this is now significantly easier to perform, since the hardest part was not having native ZIP compression support. You would want to read [ECMA-376](https://ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-376/) in order to understand the internal file format, although it might be enough to just open the file as a ZIP and take look at it yourself. It'd still probably be easier to find an existing library rather than trying to implement this in Apex, however.

---

Original Answer:

You can't do this in Apex. It lacks the binary capability to manipulate binary data in any serious capacity. However, you could use [docx.js](https://docx.js.org/) to read/write Word Document files in Aura, LWC, or Visualforce in the browser. I won't be writing a full solution, because it will require a significant amount of code, but it certainly is possible.

Comment: I tested the library, I can generate and create word documents but I cannot read an existing docx in salesforce and access its content to modify it. Do you have a sample code to do this plz?

Comment: Have you got the solution for this , i am also struggling with this ?

Comment: @SahilGupta The solution is dozens and dozens of lines of code. However, the new ZIP file support in Apex will help significantly, and I've linked the source specifications (ECMA-376) as well.